Neumann problem for Laplacian
Let $ \Omega$ be a smooth bounded domain and let $ f \in L^2(\Omega)$ such that $(f)_{\partial U}: =  \int_{\partial \Omega} f = 0  $. Then prove that
$$  \begin{cases} - \Delta u = 0 & \text{in }\Omega \\ \frac{\partial u}{\partial \nu} = f  & \text{on } \partial \Omega\end{cases}   
$$
admits a weak solution.
My strategy is as follows: We write for $v \in C^1(\Omega) : $
$$    \int_{\partial \Omega} fv = \int_{\partial \Omega} \frac{\partial u}{\partial \nu} v = \int_{\Omega} \nabla \cdot (v \nabla u) = \int_{\Omega} v \Delta u + \int_{\Omega} \nabla u \cdot \nabla v = \int_{ \Omega} \nabla u \cdot \nabla v.       
$$
We can adapt this to $v \in H^1(\Omega)$ by introducing the trace operator so that the solution is equivalent to finding
$$  \forall  f \in A . \exists  ! u \in H^1(\Omega). \forall  v \in H^1(\Omega) : B[u,v] = \langle f, Tv \rangle_{L^2(\partial \Omega)} 
$$
where $ A := \{u \in L^2 (\partial \Omega) : (u)_{\partial \Omega} = 0\}$ and $ B[u,v] := \langle \nabla u , \nabla v \rangle_{L^2(\Omega)}$.
Now the usual strategy in these existence proofs is to prove that $B$ is a bilinear continuous coercive form so that, via Lax-Milgram, $$\forall  f \in V^\star(\Omega). \exists ! u \in  V(\Omega) : B[u, - ] = \langle f, - \rangle_{L^2(\Omega)}$$ where $ V(\Omega)$ is some subspace over which $B$ satisfies the assumption.
However, the form that we want is different from $\langle  f, v \rangle$. Specifically, it is an integral on the boundary. How can I fix this situation?
I suppose the idea is then to get an intermediate $g$ such that
$$  \langle  \nabla u , \nabla v \rangle = B[u,v] = \langle  g, v \rangle_{L^2(\Omega)}  = \langle  f , Tv \rangle_{L^2(\partial \Omega)}$$
where we invoke continuity of the trace operator to get $ \langle  f, T -  \rangle$ is a linear functional on $ H^1$ so admits a unique representative $g$ which can then be solved for using Lax-Milgram.

Quick note. I guess you need $f \in L^2(\partial \Omega)$ in a trace sense. Because $\int_{\partial \Omega} f$ for $f \in L^2(\Omega)$ (usually) does not make sense

And for the linear operator you should define $f(v) := \langle f, \mathrm{trace}(v)\rangle_{L^2(\Omega)}$ which is continuous due to continuity of the trace. Are you interested in the rest of the solution?

@HyperbolicPDEfriend This is why my A is a subspace of integrable functions on the boundary. And no I think I have figured it out.
